# Swift: set Action for previous ViewController

Tags: iphone, swift

i have 2 viewControllers the first one is to allow for user to add ad details and second viewController the rules and i want to dismiss the sec vc and automatically upload the ad at first vc when user tap agree at second vc in Swift 4.2

Comment: When user goes to the next ViewController you need to perform segue with the information you want to send. Just make a research about how to use segue in swift.

Comment: yeah.i know that way. but i want to go back to first vc and upload the ad when user press agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use callbacks, a `protocol` or a `block`.

Or you can always use `UserDefaults` and ask the first vc to check the value of your key every time it appears.

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i want to send a post request to the server by Alamofire

Comment: The options are still the same, but I would suggest use callbacks to call the action and use UserDefaults to remember the user's agreement (permit or not).

Comment: Sure. In your Second ViewController, you should have a function something like this :  `func agreementButtonPressed() {delegate?.prepareAd()}`. With your delegate, you can implement the function `func prepareAd() {(your implementation)}` in your First ViewController.

Comment: Glad I could help out